# Can't create detached from AD failover cluster by DSC

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, failover, dsc

I can't create failover cluster by DSC extension. I have 2 VMs on Azure with Windows 2016 Server and SQL 2016. By DSC on both VMs I've installed following features: Failover-Clustering and RSAT-Clustering(Failover Clustering tools), and created Trusted hosts record that contains ip of each nodes.
Here part of DSC configuration that fails:

```
  Script failover
       {
           SetScript =
           {

               Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock "new-cluster -name sqlbag2 –Node node1,node2 -StaticAddress 172.16.2.100 -NoStorage –AdministrativeAccessPoint DNS"

           }
           TestScript = {
   #--If no errors return 0 or false
           $false
           }
           GetScript = {
           # Do nothing
           }
       }
```

In logs I see:

```
Set-TargetResource" on target "Executing the SetScript with the user supplied credential".
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:57] [VERBOSE] [NODE2]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]  [[Script]dnssuffixnode1]  in 2.6120 seconds.
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:58] [ERROR] PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource 
functionality with error message: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ƒ?Node node1,node2 
-StaticAddress 172.16.2.100 -NoStorage ƒ?AdministrativeAccessPoint'. 
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:58] [VERBOSE] [NODE2]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Registry][string]]
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:58] [VERBOSE] [NODE2]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Registry][string]]
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:58] [VERBOSE] [NODE2]:                            [[Registry][string]] Found registry key value 
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy' with type 'DWord' and data '1'
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:58] [VERBOSE] [NODE2]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Registry][string]]  in 0.3380 seconds.
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:58] [VERBOSE] [NODE2]: LCM:  [ Skip   Set      ]  [[Registry][string]]
VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T14:53:58] [VERBOSE] [NODE2]: LCM:  [ End    Resource ]  [[Registry][string]]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ``-ScriptBlock {}``, not ``-ScriptBlock ""``

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried that and get error:
    'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "new-cluster -name sqlbag2 ƒ?" value 
    of type "System.String" to type MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource 
    functionality with error message: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ƒ?Node node1,node2 
    -StaticAddress 172.16.2.100 -NoStorage ƒ?AdministrativeAccessPoint'.

Comment: yeah well, you do not need to do ``Invoke-Command``, just do ``new-cluster -name sqlbag2 –Node node1,node2 -StaticAddress 172.16.2.100 -NoStorage –AdministrativeAccessPoint DNS``

Comment: Not working ( VERBOSE: [2016-11-12T22:17:15] [ERROR] PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_ScriptResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource 
functionality with error message: Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "new-cluster -name sqlbag2 ƒ?" value 
of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong, does anything work in setscript? Like ``Get-Process`` or anything at all?

Comment: Found in logs next **UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand. **
But when I create it manually there isn't any problems! On both nodes added Trusted hosts

Comment: well, you probably want to start the process as a user with appropriate permissions

Comment: could you help me with this? couse  I have  on both nodes identical admins with same passwords. and there isn't any auth keys in new-cluster cmdlet

Comment: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/dsc-script-resource-and-alternate-credentials/

Comment: btw, have you seen this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xFailOverCluster-b5530c34

Comment: You might want to use the DSC resource [xFailOverCluster](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xFailOverCluster/1.5.0.0) instead of a script resource.